# File in a folder and have specific sentence

Tags: java, file

i have this program and i want it to find a file not a directory and then search a specific sentence in it and print the name of the file 
and i wrote this code and it has FileNotFoundException

```
public static void main(String[] args)  throws FileNotFoundException {  

    File file=new File("/Users/amoona/Desktop/MyDir");
    File[] matches = file.listFiles();

    for (int i=0;i<file.length();i++) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner (matches[i]);
        if (matches[i].isFile()) {
            System.out.println("It Is A File");
            while (sc.hasNext()) {
                String s = sc.next();
                if ("King AbdulAziz University".equalsIgnoreCase(s)) {
                    System.out.println(matches[i].getName());
                }  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

////////////

i changed the code to this but the issue here that it does't print the file name that have the specific sentence

File file=new File("/Users/amoona/Desktop/MyDir");
  File[] fList = file.listFiles();

```
  for(File ff : fList){
      if (ff.isDirectory()!=true){
        Scanner sc=new Scanner (ff);

           System.out.println("It Is A File");
             System.out.println(ff.getName());
           while(sc.hasNext()){
           String s=sc.nextLine();

          if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("King AbdulAziz University")){
              System.out.println("The File That Has King AbdulAziz University");
               System.out.println(ff.getName());
          }}
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which line gives you the error?

Comment: `next()` will return the next token (the default separator of tokens is the space character), so it will basically return a word, not a sentence. Try with `nextLine` .

Answer (score 1):

In your for loop you are using `i<file.length()` when you should be using `i<matches.length`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your method:

1) As others have stated, your for loop is using `file.length()` and it should be `matches.length` -matches is an array - you don't need the ()

2) Creating a `Scanner` to access a file should be placed after the `if(subFile.isFile())` check. You don't want to open a scanner on a directory or an 'Access Denied' error is possible and likely.

3) In your if condition: `if (matches[i].isFile()==true)`, you dont need the '==true' part. Although this is syntactically correct, it is unnecessary, since the `isFile()` returns a boolean and is all you need in the if check.

Here is your method, slightly modified to include the above points:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  throws FileNotFoundException{

    File file=new File("/Users/amoona/Desktop/MyDir");
    File[] matches = file.listFiles();


    for(int i=0;i<matches.length;i++){
        File subFile = matches[i];

        if (subFile.isFile()){
          System.out.println("Checking the file: " + subFile.getPath());
          Scanner sc=new Scanner (subFile);

          while(sc.hasNext()){
              String s=sc.nextLine();

              if ("King AbdulAziz University".equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
                  System.out.println("=====>> Found a match! " + subFile.getPath());
              }
          }
       }
   }
}
```